# Is it possible to include a js fragment inside another js file with webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a JavaScript file that is not a module of any sort, and I am not allowed to turn it into any sort of module.

I want to include the body of that javascript inside of another one using webpack.

My JavaScript that I want to include is

```js
'use strict';

const OldScript = function() {
  let example_lib = {
    propertyhere: 1,
  };

  return example_lib;
};
```

and the head file that is used to build my bundle.is

```
console.log(OldScript);
```

What I would like to come out in my bundle is something that looks like this

```js
'use strict';

const OldScript = function() {
  let example_lib = {
    propertyhere: 1,
  };

  return example_lib;
};

console.log(OldScript);
```

If at all possible, however I know that it is seldom possible to get what one wants. Therefore I would like to generate a bundle out of these two scripts so that the console log no longer shows OldScript to be undefined, but rather a function, and that if I were to execute that function in my entry script it would return the object shown above.

I would imagine this were done some sort of require statement inside of the entry point script, but I starting to think that is not possible.

Comment: "I have a JavaScript file that is not a module of any sort, and I am not allowed to turn it into any sort of module." May I ask why? Could you please add more details about your final goal?

Comment: Well, it is a third party javascript that is old style js that addresses a particular functionality and we do not have rights to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "convert" it into a module only for your usage with [`exports-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader), which allows you to specify what would be exported from the file.

```
npm install exports-loader --save-dev
```

Assuming that the 3rd party file name is **external.js**.

```js
// my file that gets bundled with webpack
const OldScript = require('exports-loader?OldScript!./path-to/external.js'); // this is "inline" usage of webpack loader.

console.log(OldScript); // this will work with the function that is inside external.js
```